# Hiding panel control of parent form when child form is shown

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to hide Panel control of `parent Form2` when button is clicked in `GroupSelect childform` that opens another `child form GroupExmStart`, when this GroupExmStart form gets open than panel4 should hide and when it closes than it should be visible, I tried the following code but it's not working and nothing is happening also. Where am I going wrong, how can I do it the right way?

**Parent Form**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Control control
    {
        //using this I accessed panel4 in child form GroupSelect
        get {return this.panel4; }
    }
}
```

**Child Form**

```
public partial class GroupSelect : Form
{
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2(lgnName);
        frm2.panel4.Visible = false;

        GroupExmStart grpexamfrm = new GroupExmStart(GrpID, DurationID, lgnName);
        grpexamfrm.MdiParent = this.ParentForm;
        //showing another child form and 
        grpexamfrm.Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works very well for me

**In Parent form**

```
public Form2(string userName)
        {
        InitializeComponent();            
        panelHide = panel4;
        }
public static Panel panelHide = new Panel();
```

**In GroupSelect child form**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2.panelHide.Hide();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are creating new form2 but as I understand the question yor parent form is Form2, so you can do as below

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   var frm2  = this.Parent as Form2;
   if(frm2 !=null)
        frm2.control.Visible = false;

   GroupExmStart grpexamfrm = new GroupExmStart(GrpID, DurationID,lgnName);
   grpexamfrm.MdiParent = this.ParentForm;
   grpexamfrm.Show();//showing another child form and 
}
```

Comment: I tried your code ,Still That panel is visible ,this Panel Contains 3 Picture Boxes

Comment: yor `Child Form` created by which form?

Comment: GroupSelect(Child form) is created by `Form2(Parent Form)` and GroupExamStart(another Child Form) is created by GroupSelect(Child form)